# Minimize fullscreen application

Tags: fullscreen

How can i minimize a fullscreen application? Alt-F9 does not seem to have any effect on fullscreen windows.

More specifically, I'm running Boxee in fullscreen on Ubuntu 10.10. And when Boxee hangs, I want to minimize the window so I can kill it.

Comment: Full screen applications take full control over the input, so alt-f9 is never received.If it's frozen,you wont be able to minimize it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a few options for a frozen full screen app :

- Go to a virtual terminal (CTRL-ALT-F1), issue your killall command on the offending process, then switch back to the GUI (CTRL-ALT-F7).

or

- Create a hot-key to switch to another virtual desktop.  You should be able to do that by going to system/preferences/Keyboard Shortcuts.  Then scroll down to Window Management and create a hotkey for "Switch to Workspace x".

and my favourite :

- Still in Keyboard Shortcuts, click the "Add" button, then put "xkill" as the command, and give it a name like "Kill Window", then assign something like CTRL-ALT-D.  Next time your Boxee crashes, hit CTRL-ALT-D on your keyboard, then click your mouse button.  Since it's fullscreen, the click should kill Boxee.

Comment: the click should not be needed with most applications.

Comment: The click is needed if you run xkill without any arguments.  At least, it's needed if you run it the way I've described.

Answer (score 1):

If boxee hangs, you might be able to switch to another tty.
To do that use:

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f1</kbd> *(or f2->12)*

once you are on a tty, login using your username and password.
Now type

`killall boxee` or `sudo killall boxee` *(you will need to type your password if you use sudo).*

(guessing this is the name of the boxee executable as I don't use boxee), and press enter. If it does not complain, and returns you to a prompt, press

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f7</kbd> *(or f9, though it could be another tty where your desktop is located)*

To return to your desktop.

Answer (score 0):

For notepad++, running on Wine, specifically:
If you're in notepad++, you've (while being in notepad++) pressed <kbd>Windows-Key</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>, and now there is NO 'Minimize' button at top right (like usual) and you've also lost all your toolbar options (e.g. File, Edit, Search, etc.), then press the small '+' button at top right to revert to normal mode (as it was before the <kbd>Windows-Key</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> press).

Comment: Hello. This is the REVERSE of what was asked.